# Multi ring buffer failure in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, buffer

I am trying to open multi ring buffer in ArcGIS Pro 3, but when I click the tool, the whole map document crashes.

Could you tell me what is the problem and how can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Same here, I executed the command without issue on ArcGIS Pro 3.0. I imported a shp (CRS units in meters) and I followed [the steps @PolyGeo did](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/446027/115):

1. started ArcGIS Pro 3.0 without a template
2. imported a shp
3. used Command Search bar to search for and open the Multiple Ring Buffer tool

Bellow you can see the parameters I tested.
[image: multiple buffer ring]

Comment: Thank you. But it is still not working maybe I need to uninstall

Comment: I don't know if that's the issue, but check the CRS of your data. If it's not in meters then try to reproject them and re-run the algorithm.

Comment: I used the other computer and it worked

Comment: So I guess you should accept @PolyGeo 's answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

To test this, I:

1. started ArcGIS Pro 3.0.2 without a template
2. used Command Search bar to search for and open the Multiple Ring Buffer tool

The Multiple Ring Buffer tool opened without a problem.

If doing the same thing does not work for you, then I think you should uninstall and reinstall ArcGIS Pro, and try it again.